# Prim's algorithm on graph with weights of only 1 and 2 on each edge using two lists

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Given a weighted, connected, simple undirected graph G with weights of only 1 and 2 on each edge

I want to implement [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm) this way:

the weights are either 1 or 2,  so I can simply store the edges in 2 separate lists, one for edges with weight 1, and the second for edges with weight 2.

To find the edge with lowest weight I simply take one from the first list, unless it is empty, in which case I take an edge from the second list.

Accessing and deleting an element from a list is O(1) so Prim's algorithm will run in O(V+E).

```
package il.ac.oranim.alg2016;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*; 

public class MST12 {    
    private int weight; // weight of the tree
    private Edge[] mstEdges; // use this to store the edges of your Minimum Spanning Tree

    public MST12(EdgeWeightedGraph G, int s)  throws IndexOutOfBoundsException, DisconnectedGraphException, WrongWeightException {
        // check that the starting vertex is in the range 0,1,...,G.V()
        if (s < 0 || s >= G.V()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        // check that the input graph is connected otherwise there is no (minimum) spanning tree
        if (isConnected(G) == false) {
            throw new DisconnectedGraphException();
        }
        // check that all the weights are 1 or 2
        for (Edge e : G.edges()) {
            if (e.weight() != 1 && e.weight() != 2) {
                throw new WrongWeightException();
            }
        }

        this.weight = 0; // make sure you update this value

        // replace -->
        // your code goes here
        // <-- replace
    }

    // returns the weight of the tree
    public int weight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    // checks whether a graph is connected
    private static boolean isConnected(EdgeWeightedGraph G) {
        // create a graph of class Graph with the same edges (weights)
        Graph g = new Graph(G.V());
        for (Edge e : G.edges()) {
            int v = e.either();
            g.addEdge(v, e.other(v));
        }
        // compute the connected components of the graph
        CC cc = new CC(g);

        // return true iff there is only one connected component
        return cc.count() == 1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the edges in a minimum spanning tree as
     *    an iterable of edges
     */
    public Iterable<Edge> edges() {
        Queue<Edge> edges = new Queue<Edge>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.mstEdges.length; i++) {
            Edge e = this.mstEdges[i];
            int v = e.either();
            edges.enqueue(new Edge(v, e.other(v), e.weight()));
        }
        return edges;
    }

    /**
     * test the computing of an MST of a graph with weights 1 and 2 only
     * the first argument is the name of the file that contains the graph (graph1.txt, graph2.txt, or graph3.txt)
     * you can define this argument in Run.. --> (x)=Arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        EdgeWeightedGraph G = new EdgeWeightedGraph(in);

        PrimMST primMST = new PrimMST(G);       
        MST12 mst12 = null;
        try {
            mst12 = new MST12(G,0);
        }
        catch (DisconnectedGraphException e) {
            System.err.println("the input graph is not connected and hence has no (minimum) spanning tree");
        }
        catch (WrongWeightException e) {
            System.err.println("not all weights in the input graph are 1 or 2");            
        }

        System.out.println("Prim's MST weight = " + primMST.weight());
        System.out.println("My MST's weight = " + mst12.weight());
    }
}
```

> I am stuck at the part of `//replace-->//your code goes here//replace<--`

two classes that needed:

```
package il.ac.oranim.alg2016;

public class DisconnectedGraphException extends Exception {
    public DisconnectedGraphException() {}
}
```

and

```
  package il.ac.oranim.alg2016;

  public class WrongWeightException extends Exception {
      public WrongWeightException() {}
  }
```

Also I'm allowed to use all this http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

> can someone help me please with this part `//replace-->//your code goes here//replace<--`

I tried to copy [This](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/PrimMST.java.html) code to the `//<--relpace,//replace-->` part and then to feet it, to change it from using a heap to two lists.

[Pseudocode of Prim's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66498/44719)

In other words I need code for this:

[image]

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Have you tried to implement the solution with two lists which is described in your post? If yes, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  package il.ac.oranim.alg2016;

 import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*; 

 public class MST_12
{   
private int weight; // weight of the tree
private Edge[] mstEdges; // MST edges

private boolean[] marked;// MST vertices
private Queue<Edge> queueWeight1; 
private Queue<Edge> queueWeight2; 

   public MST_12(EdgeWeightedGraph G, int s)  throws      IndexOutOfBoundsException, DisconnectedGraphException, WrongWeightException 
{
    // check that the starting vertex is in the range 0,1,...,G.V()
    if (s < 0 || s >= G.V()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    // check that the input graph is connected otherwise there is no (minimum) spanning tree
    if (isConnected(G) == false) {
        throw new DisconnectedGraphException();
    }
    // check that all the weights are 1 or 2
    for (Edge e : G.edges()) {
        if (e.weight() != 1 && e.weight() != 2) {
            throw new WrongWeightException();
        }
    }

    this.weight = 0; // make sure you update this value

    // replace -->

    queueWeight1 = new Queue<Edge>();
    queueWeight2 = new Queue<Edge>();
    mstEdges=new Edge[G.V()];
    marked=new boolean[G.V()];  

     for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)      // run from each vertex to find
            if (!marked[v]) KPrim(G,v);// minimum spanning forest
}

  private void KPrim ( EdgeWeightedGraph G, int s)
    {
         visit(G,s);
         while (!queueWeight1.isEmpty()||!queueWeight2.isEmpty()){   
              Edge e=null;
              if (!queueWeight1.isEmpty())
                 { e=queueWeight1.dequeue();}
              else if (!queueWeight2.isEmpty()){e=queueWeight2.dequeue();}
              int v=e.either(), w=e.other(v);
              assert marked [v]||marked [w];
              if(marked[v]&&marked[w]) continue;
              mstEdges[s]=e;
              weight+=e.weight();
              if(!marked[v]) visit(G,v);// v becomes part of tree
              if(!marked[w]) visit(G,w);// w becomes part of a tree
         }          
    }

//add all edges e incident to v onto queue if the other endpoint has not yet been scanned
    private void visit (EdgeWeightedGraph G, int v)
    {
    marked[v]=true;// add v to T
    for (Edge e : G.adj(v))// for each edge e=v-w, add to queueWeight if w not already in T  
    { 
       if(!marked[e.other(v)])  {       
            if (e.weight()==1.0) {queueWeight1.enqueue(e);mstEdges[v]=e;}//add the smallest edge weight to the mst weight
            else {queueWeight2.enqueue(e);mstEdges[v]=e;}}}

    }

    // <-- replace


// returns the weight of the tree
public int weight() {
    return this.weight;
}

// checks whether a graph is connected
private static boolean isConnected(EdgeWeightedGraph G) {
    // create a graph of class Graph with the same edges (weights)
    Graph g = new Graph(G.V());
    for (Edge e : G.edges()) {
        int v = e.either();
        g.addEdge(v, e.other(v));
    }
    // compute the connected components of the graph
    CC cc = new CC(g);

    // return true iff there is only one connected component
    return cc.count() == 1;
}

/**
 * Returns the edges in a minimum spanning tree as
 *    an iterable of edges
 */
public Iterable<Edge> edges() {
    Queue<Edge> edges = new Queue<Edge>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.mstEdges.length; i++) {
        Edge e = this.mstEdges[i];
        int v = e.either();
        edges.enqueue(new Edge(v, e.other(v), e.weight()));
    }
    return edges;
}

/**
 * test the computing of an MST of a graph with weights 1 and 2 only
 * the first argument is the name of the file that contains the graph (graph1.txt, graph2.txt, or graph3.txt)
 * you can define this argument in Run.. --> (x)=Arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    In in = new In(args[0]);
    EdgeWeightedGraph G = new EdgeWeightedGraph(in);

    PrimMST primMST = new PrimMST(G);       
    MST_12 mst12 = null;
    try {
        mst12 = new MST_12(G,0);
    }
    catch (DisconnectedGraphException e) {
        System.err.println("the input graph is not connected and hence has no (minimum) spanning tree");
    }
    catch (WrongWeightException e) {
        System.err.println("not all weights in the input graph are 1 or 2");            
    }

    System.out.println("Prim's MST weight = " + primMST.weight());
    System.out.println("My MST's weight = " + mst12.weight());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, implement normal Prim's Algorithm with a priority queue that runs in O(|E|log(|V|)). And do it yourself instead of copying the book's code. If you can't implement Prim's Algorithm yourself, there's no way you'll understand how to extend to the algorithm.

Then, as D.W. suggested at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/prims-algorithm-on-graph-with-weights-of-only-1-and-2-on-each-edge you can change your ExtractMin, Remove, and Insert functions to be O(1).

The idea is that you can keep a list of edges of weight 1 and 2. If the list for edge weight 1 is not empty, then you can get the next best edge to use by popping off the list in O(1) time. If the list for edge weight 1 is empty, then the next best edges can be obtained by popping off the list of weight 2 in O(1) time.

The only change from normal Prim's Algorithm is that you'll need is a data structure like this:

```
private class SpecialPQ {
    ArrayList<NodeWeightPair> _queueWeight1 = new ArrayList<NodeWeightPair>();
    ArrayList<NodeWeightPair> _queueWeight2 = new ArrayList<NodeWeightPair>();

    public void insert(NodeWeightPair e) {
        if (e._weight == 1) {
            _queueWeight1.add(e);
        }
        else {
            _queueWeight2.add(e);
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (_queueWeight1.size() == 0) {
            _queueWeight2.remove(_queueWeight2.size()-1);
        }
        else {
            _queueWeight1.remove(_queueWeight1.size()-1);
        }
    }

    public NodeWeightPair extractMin() {
        if (_queueWeight1.size() > 0) {
            return _queueWeight1.get(_queueWeight1.size()-1);
        }
        else {
            return _queueWeight2.get(_queueWeight2.size()-1);
        }
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return _queueWeight1.size() == 0 && _queueWeight2.size() == 0;
    }
};
```

Normal Prim's Algorithm uses a binary heap priority queue to get O(|E|log(|V|)). You just have to replace the binary heap priority queue with this faster `SpecialPQ`.

So the book's code has this line:

```
private IndexMinPQ<Double> pq;
```

You'll just need to change that to

```
private SpecialPQ pq;
```

and get the rest of the code to compile. Don't literally copy and paste my code for `SpecialPQ`. It'll take you a long time get it compatible with the book's code. Instead, I think you should write your own `SpecialPQ` that will work with your own implementation of Prim's Algorithm.

I have a working example locally - my own implementation, so it's not compatible with the book's code. I'll share mine if you post your attempt at implementing this.

Edits:

NodeWeightPair

```
private class NodeWeightPair {

    private int _parent;
    private int _node;
    private int _weight;
    public NodeWeightPair(int parent, int node, int weight) {
        _node = node;
        _weight = weight;
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show the classes of `ArrayList` and `NodeWeightPair` ?

Comment: I added in `NodeWeightPair`. `ArrayList` is `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Your SpecialPQ is more like priority stack... Why do you prefer ArrayList over, say, LinkedList?

Comment: Regardless of whether I use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, `extractMin` still gives you the next smallest element. Runtime is still the same - O(1) to pop off the end of an `ArrayList` and O(1) to poll from the front of a `Queue` represented as a `LinkedList`. It doesn't seem that memory is as big an issue as runtime for this problem. I just choose `ArrayList` because at some extra memory cost, the memory is allocated in a contiguous block, which *may* lead to more cache hits and lower absolute (not asymptotic) runtime compared to `LinkedList`.

Comment: Why prefer ArrayList over a Stack object?

Comment: No reason. If you prefer a Stack, feel free to use it.